# Why screen readers doesn't read any label?

Tags: android, flutter, label, accessibility, android-framelayout

My app run fine in emulator. But when i download it from google play store, it doesn't work. Google play comsole suggest me to give a label to `android:id/content/FrameLayout[1]` because FrameLayout cannot be readable from screen reader

i used Semantics widget to solve problem. But it didn't work